# Firefox extension upgrade: distinguish betw. user-initiated vs. auto-update

Tags: firefox-addon

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload#options.loadReason provides a (indirect) way to listen for an add-on upgrade event (loadReason == “upgrade”).

Is there a programmatic way to detect whether the upgrade was user-initiated, or was an auto-update?

a) User-initiated (user goes to my web site and installs the latest version of the add-on): once the new version is loaded, I’d like to pop a new tab/URL that says “Thank you for upgrading...”

b) Auto-update (update.rdf): No user messaging.

However, in both the a) and b) scenarios, my exports.main() is seeing loadReason == “upgrade”, so I don’t know how to distinguish between the two.

Any workaround suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is a cool question. I'm not sure myself but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Addon there we see something called `foreignInstall`. To access that do this:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm');
AddonManager.getAddonByID('NativeShot@jetpack', function(addon) {
    console.log(addon.foreignInstall)
});
```

I'm not sure what qualifies as "third party installation".